# Android update is installing app again

Tags: android, installation, version

I have searched through the forum, but found no match for the issue I am currently facing:

I have an app, which installs and works ok, but when I try to update it (install again), the application does not update, but is installed separately one more time - I get two shortcuts, different app data, both versions work, etc.

I have not changed the application name, have observed the same behavior in adb and with actual phone and tablet, also tried with same and increased app version...

This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.rts.android.language" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.1"
android:installLocation="auto">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name="com.rts.android.language.ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter> 
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any ideas what the reason might be?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your manifest code here?

Comment: You have the same package name for both the apk right? it must

Comment: Yes, same package name too, here is the manifest:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.rts.android.language"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.1"
      android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Comment: `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.rts.android.language.ui.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>`

Comment: Actually the biggest changes between the two versions are:
- adding the vibration permission + some minor vibration-based features in code
- changing the app icon

Comment: @MerlinBG Maybe there are differences between the old and the new manifest.
It will be more helpfull if you will add your new and old manifast...

Comment: @choop, the only change in manifest between both versions is the addition of the vibration permission and increasing versionName from 1 to 1.1:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, make sure both applications contain same package name?

```
package="com.rts.android.language"
```

Comment: I found out that the deployed version on all devices has a typo in the namespace, also the change is not checked in in the cvs. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to rename your activity: 
from: 
    `<activity android:name="com.rts.android.language.ui.MainActivity" />` 
to :  
    `<activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity" />`

Try to clean your project then build/rebuild...
When doing that you need to clean your Keystore:
`%USERPROFILE%/.androidon` Windows 
`~/.android/debug.keystore` on Linux and Mac OS X

Comment: It didn't, but I found out that the deployed version on all devices has a typo in the namespace, also the change is not checked in in the cvs. Thanks for the help.